# How to verify string is empty

Tags: php

I'm getting VIN number from FORM, but sometimes user do not enter anything and just send blanked form.

I need to debug it so I add something like:

```
   if (isset($this->vin)) 
    {
    //CODE HERE
    }
```

Problem is i am still getting empty string to my database. So I var_dump($this->vin) and if user do not enter VIN var dump says: string(0) ""

So I edit my statement to :

```
if (isset($this->vin) || $this->vin != "")        
{
//CODE HERE
}
```

But still didn't help, guys any hint how I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Change `||` to `&&` because you want that it is set AND it is not empty

Comment: Use the `&&` operator. Plus, use `!empty()` instead of `!=""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->vin is always set (assume that you set it from post so it exists)

Try:

```
if(!empty(trim($this->vin)))
{//check if empty even if spaces are introduced
}
```

Comment: Working, thank you will mark this answer as soon I will be able to

Answer (score 1):

You can use !empty expression

```
if ( !empty($this->vin) ) {
//Code here
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: thumb up for correct answer, how ever KA_lin was first so I mark his answer as correct